# Extract data from URL

Tags: ruby

I would like to get some data from a URL in Ruby. I have a URL matching:

```
"http://localhost:3000/cars/test/1/direction/2"
```

I would like to extract the value after `/test` (here it is `1`). I know how to extract the other values.

I created a URI object:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/cars/test/1/direction/2")
uri.port = 3000
uri.path = /cars/test/1/direction/2
uri.host = localhost
```

But, I don't know how to extract the internal parameters.

Do I have to parse this URL or is there an existing solution?

Comment: is this rails ? If so you can probably use params if not you could use a basic regex like `\/(\w+)\/(\d+)` which used with `String#scan` will be `[["test","1"],["direction","2"]]`

Comment: No it isn't. I am creating custom gem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your sample code isn't valid. It's important that it be runnable when asking for help, because people will need to use it as the basis for helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work well for you as it identifies the leading name as well:

```
url_parts = uri.path.scan(/\/(\w+)\/(\d+)/)
#=> [["test","1"],["direction","2"]]
```

Then you could even make it a `Hash` using:

```
Hash[url_parts]
#=> {"test" => "1", "direction" => "2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy solution is to just use `split`.

```
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/cars/test/1/direction/2")
url_path = uri.path
url_parts = url_path.split("/")
url_parts[3] # => "1"
```